# What is the probability that the number $5$ comes up on exactly two of three loaded dice?

Tags: probability, dice

I roll three different loaded dice. For the first die, the probability of getting a $5$ is $0.7$, for the second die the probability of getting a $5$ is $0.48$, and for the third die the probability of getting a $5$ is $0.38$.

What is the probability that the number $5$ comes up on exactly two of the three dice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rolling three dice...am I doing this correctly?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300965/rolling-three-dice-am-i-doing-this-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E_i$ is the event that dice $i$ ($i=1,2,3$) comes up a $5$, then the event of getting exactly two 5s is
$$
\big(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3^c\big)\cup\big(E_1 \cap E_2^c \cap E_3\big)\cup(E_1^c \cap E_2 \cap E_3\big)
$$
Each of the pieces in parentheses is disjoint from the others (why!?) so using the properties of the probability $P$, 
$$
P(\text{exactly two } 5s) = P\big\{\big(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3^c\big)\cup\big(E_1 \cap E_2^c \cap E_3\big)\cup(E_1^c \cap E_2 \cap E_3\big)\big\} = 
P\big(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3^c\big) + P\big(E_1 \cap E_2^c \cap E_3\big)+P\big(E_1^c \cap E_2 \cap E_3\big).
$$
Now, assuming that the $E_i$ are independent,
$$
P\big(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3^c\big) + P\big(E_1 \cap E_2^c \cap E_3\big)+P\big(E_1^c \cap E_2 \cap E_3\big) = P(E_1)P(E_2)P(E_3^c) + P(E_1)P(E_2^c)P(E_3) +P(E_1^c)P(E_2)P(E_3)
$$
and now you can figure out the right side of the last equality with the information you're given.

Comment: How do you find the P(not a five) for any of the dice

Comment: For any event $E$, $P(E^c) = 1-P(E)$. So, $P(\text{not a five}) = 1 - P(\text{is a five})$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the probability of each die coming up $5$ is different, we can't short-cut this by using combinatorics. We have to consider all the possibilities.

Let's call the probability that a die comes up $5$ "$F$", and not-$5$ "$G$". Then, let's label each of the dice with a suffix of $1$, $2$, or $3$.

Of course, the $G$ value for each die is $1$ minus the $F$ value.

As you said "exactly $2$", then we must consider all the combinations with exactly $2$ $F$'s and $1$ $G$. Namely:

$$P = F1 \times F2 \times G3 + F1 \times G2 \times F3 + G1 \times F2 \times F3$$

$$= 0.7 \times 0.48 \times (1-0.38) + 0.7 \times (1-0.48) \times .38 + (1-0.7) \times 0.48 \times 0.38$$

$$= 0.40136.$$