# Rolling three dice. Probability that two of them show the same value, but third does not

Tags: probability, statistics

If we consider $D_1,D_2,D_3$, and that two dices must show the same value, we have a total of $^3C_2$ ways this can happen.

That being said, the first die can be anything ($6/6$), then second die must be the same number $(1/6)$ chance, and the third die must be something else $(5/6)$. Therefore, the solution is:

$(^3C_2)(6/6)(1/6)(5/6)=5/12$

I would like to point out that there is already a question same as mine:

[Rolling three dice...am I doing this correctly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300965/rolling-three-dice-am-i-doing-this-correctly)

My question is that, we must roll two dices which show the **same value**. The question doesn't give us an exact value (like $1,2$). Therefore, wouldn't it make sense to perform $^6C_1$ to select **any** of the values beforehand? This changes our answer to become $6\cdot(^3C_2)(6/6)(1/6)(5/6)=5/2>0$

This clearly does not make sense as the probability is greater then $0$, but why else **must we not multiply by 6**.

On [this](http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/probability/calcdice.htm) website, it says the following

> The probability of one dice being a particular number is 1/6. The probability of two dice being the same particular number is 1/6 x 1/6 = 1/36. This is not the same as saying that both dice are the same number. There are six different possible numbers, so that would be 6/36 or 1/6.

"This is not the same as saying that both dice are the same number. There are six different possible numbers, so that would be 6/36 or 1/6."

Following this information I multiply by $6$? What is my point of confusion here?

Comment: If you multiply by $6$ due to there being $6$ possibilities for the repeated value, then the probability that the first die lands on that value becomes 1/6 rather than 6/6. So you'll get the same answer.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *already* multiplied by $6$ ways to select a number for the pair, *and* the $5$ ways to select a different number.$$\def\cbinom#1#2{{^{#1}\mathsf C_{#2}}} \cbinom 32\cdot\cbinom 61(\tfrac 16)^2\cdot\cbinom 51\tfrac 16 = \cbinom 32\tfrac{6\cdot 5}{6^3}$$

Comment: We need 2 uniquely different outcomes. Matches simulation result from R software (+1): code `u=replicate( 10^6, length(unique(sample(1:6, 3, rep=T))) );  mean(u==2)` returns 0.416565 on one run (0.417339 on next). Both
$\approx 5/12.$